# Implement generic interface: construct causes code to be less generic than indicated by the type annotations

Tags: f#

I need to implement an interface like this:

```cs
interface IEvent<T> : IEvent {
  T Data { get; }
}
```

```cs
public interface IEvent
{
  Guid Id { get; set; }
  long Version { get; set; }
  long Sequence { get; set; }
  object Data { get; }
  Guid StreamId { get; set; }
  string StreamKey { get; set; }
  DateTimeOffset Timestamp { get; set; }
  string TenantId { get; set; }
  Type EventType { get; }
  string EventTypeName { get; set; }
  string DotNetTypeName { get; set; }
}
```

That's what I came up with:

```ml
type WrappedEvent<'T>(x: 'T) =
    interface Events.IEvent with
      member val Data = x with get
      member val DotNetTypeName = null with get, set
      member val EventType = null
      member val EventTypeName = null with get, set
      member val Id = Guid.Empty with get, set
      member val Sequence = int64 (0) with get, set
      member val StreamId = Guid.Empty with get, set
      member val StreamKey = null with get, set
      member val TenantId = null with get, set
      member val Timestamp = DateTimeOffset.MinValue with get, set
      member val Version = int64 (0) with get, set
```

`WrappedEvent` is used like this:

```ml
let MapToSubtype subtype =
    match subtype with
    | CustomerRegistered registeredCustomer -> WrappedEvent<CustomerRegisteredEvent> registeredCustomer :> Events.IEvent
    | CustomerDeleted deletedCustomer -> WrappedEvent<CustomerDeletedEvent> deletedCustomer :> Events.IEvent
```

The compiler throws an error for `<'T>` at `WrappedEvent<'T>`

```
This type parameter has been used in a way that constrains it to always be 'obj'
This code is less generic than required by its annotations because the explicit type variable 'T' could not be generalized. 
It was constrained to be 'obj'.
```

A warning is shown for `Data` at `member val Data`:

```
This construct causes code to be less generic than indicated by the type annotations. 
The type variable 'T has been constrained to be type 'obj'.
```

How do I solve this?

Update:

If I'm implementing the interface like this `interface Events.IEvent<'T> with` (using the generic parameter), I get this error:

```
No implementation was given for 'Events.IEvent.get_Data() : obj'. 
Note that all interface members must be implemented and listed under an appropriate 'interface' declaration, e.g. 'interface ... with member ...'.
```

Comment: Did you forget to specify the interface's generic parameter? Could there be a different interface also named `IEvent`, but not generic? That's a common pattern from the early days of .NET

Comment: @FyodorSoikin you mean like `interface Events.IEvent<'T> with`?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin I've added more information to the question

Comment: So you're not implementing `IEvent<T>` at all, right? Wasn't that the goal?

Comment: I've changed it to `interface Events.IEvent<'T> with`  and now I get the error `No implementation was given for 'Events.IEvent.get_Data() : obj'. `

Comment: So `IEvent<T>` wants me to return `T Data` and `IEvent` wants me to return `object Data`. How do I solve this as `IEvent<T>` inherits `IEvent`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First**, you're implementing *two* interfaces here, not one, - `IEvent<T>` and its base interface `IEvent`. As such, you need to add two `interface ... with` blocks - one for each:

```
type WrappedEvent<'T>(x: 'T) =
    interface Events.IEvent<'T> with
      member val Data = x with get

    interface Events.IEvent with
      member val Data = x with get
      member val DotNetTypeName = null with get, set
      member val EventType = null
      ...
```

**Second**, when implementing the `IEvent` interface, note the type of its `Data` member: it's `obj`. So if you initialize that member with `x`, it follows that `x` must have type `obj`. And that's the source of your original error: `x` is used in such a way that will make it constrained to `obj`.

To fix this, you need to downcast `x` to `obj` before initializing `Data` with it:

```
    interface Events.IEvent with
      member val Data = x :> obj with get
```

But wait! This will *still* not work. The problem is, `member val` declares not just a property, but also a backing *field* for it. And now you're declaring two different backing fields, both named `Data`, but of different types. (also, btw, you don't actually need separate backing fields, right? because you already have `x`)

So to get around that, make them properties without backing fields:

```
    interface Events.IEvent<'T> with
        member self.Data with get() = x

    interface Events.IEvent with
        member self.Data with get() = x :> obj
        ...
```

Comment: Thanks, now everything works as expected.